# Is there a way to eliminate the repeating function in Lua?

Tags: lua

I have the following `delayed` functions that are called 500ms after each button is pressed.

```
function M.delayed1()
  for i = 1, #presses do
    if presses[i].num == 1 then
      presses[i].holdMode = true
      presses[i].shouldUntrigger = false
      return
    end
  end
end

function M.delayed2()
  for i = 1, #presses do
    if presses[i].num == 2 then
      presses[i].holdMode = true
      presses[i].shouldUntrigger = false
      return
    end
  end
end

function M.delayed3()
  for i = 1, #presses do
    if presses[i].num == 3 then
      presses[i].holdMode = true
      presses[i].shouldUntrigger = false
      return
    end
  end
end

function M.delayed4()
  for i = 1, #presses do
    if presses[i].num == 4 then
      presses[i].holdMode = true
      presses[i].shouldUntrigger = false
      return
    end
  end
end
```

Actually, the code is much longer because I use a total of 64 buttons.
I wonder if it is possible to reduce the amount of code in Lua in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the table entries of `M` in loop, assigning [closures](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html) with the loop index as an upvalue.

```lua
local M = {}
for n = 1, 64 do
  M["delayed" .. tostring(n)] = function()
    for i = 1, #presses do
      if presses[i].num == n then
        presses[i].holdMode = true
        presses[i].shouldUntrigger = false
        return
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@Henri has the you are looking for; But I wonder why you create 64 function duplicates in the first place? They seem all to do the same logic, so why not have one single function that receives a parameter with the presses number instead? The function definition would look like...

```
local function delayed(presses_array, press_num)
    for id, press in ipairs(presses_array) do
        if press.num == press_num then
            press.holdMode = true
            press.shouldUntrigger = false
            break
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: In the original task the identity of the called function was providing the needed info to the loop. The closure does the same, storing the info in an upvalue, and referencing the loop code - it's shared by all closures, not copied. With your code you also has a single instance of the loop, but now you have to find a way to report the id to the function, which wasn't there in the original post. And possibly it's not easily retrievable, if the `delayed` function is called as a callback from a gui element which doesn't provide additional user data.